# Нужно заменить функцию ungetc, на другую функцию не связанную с потоком c ci/o c++

Tags: c++, c, потоки-данных

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

double number(){ // считываем число
    int res = 0;
    for (;;)//бесконечный цикл
    {
        char c; 
        scanf_s("%c", &c);//записываем
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')//условие, что используются только цифры
            res = res *10 + c - '0';//для корректной записи числа
        else {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            
            break;//прерываем
        }
        
    }
    return res;//возвращаем результат

}


double plmn();//чтобы компилятор увидел функцию в фактор

double skobki() {//скобки

    char c;
    scanf_s("%c", &c);
    if (c == '(') {
        double x = plmn();
        
        return x;
    }
    else {//если не число,то
        ungetc(c, stdin);//возвращаем символ
        return number();
    }
}

double factor() { // функция деления и умножения
    double x =skobki();
    for (;;) {
        char c;
        scanf_s("%c", &c);
    
        switch (c) {
        case '*': // если умножение
            x *= skobki();
            break;
        case '/': // если деление 
            x /= skobki();
            break;
        default: //если неизвестный символ, то возвращаем в поток
            ungetc(c, stdin);// возвращаем символ назад 
            return x;//возвращаем результат
        }
    }
}
double plmn() { // функция сложения и вычитания
    double x = factor();
    for (;;) {
        char c;
        scanf_s("%c", &c);

        switch (c) {
        case '+': // если сложение
            x += factor();
            break;
        case '-': // если вычитание
            x -= factor();
            break;
        default: //если неизвестный символ, то возвращаем в поток
            ungetc(c, stdin);// возвращаем символ назад 
            return x; //возвращаем результат
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double r = plmn();//вызов функций по порядку
    printf("Result= %0.3f", r);//результат
}
```

преподаватель запретил использовать потоки, то есть ungetc не подходит

Comment: Поясните проблему более детально. Что значит "другую функцию не связанную с потоком c ci/o c++"?

Comment: Если задан такой бред (нельзя использовать готовую `ungetc()`), то надо ее эмулировать. Проще всего  без буферизации. Заведите свой "поток" (структуру) в котором храните ссылку на файл из которого читаете очередной символ (например, функцией read) и место под символ, который возвращаете в "поток". Если такой символ есть, то при обращении к потоку из функции Get возвращаете его и ставите признак -- нет такого символа. Если его нет, то вызов Get возвращает очередной символ, поставляемый функцией read. Надеюсь принцип ясен, остальные детали сами додумайте

Answer (score -1):

Если задан такой бред (нельзя использовать готовую `ungetc()`), то надо ее эмулировать. Проще всего без буферизации. Заведите свой "поток" (структуру) в котором храните ссылку на файл из которого читаете очередной символ (например, функцией read) и место под символ, который возвращаете в "поток". Если такой символ есть, то при обращении к потоку из функции Get возвращаете его и ставите признак -- нет такого символа. Если его нет, то вызов Get возвращает очередной символ, поставляемый функцией read. Надеюсь принцип ясен, остальные детали сами додумайте

Comment: А зачем вам второй аккаунт? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398230/